# Different results for IRR computation between R and MS Excel

Tags: r, excel, irr

The internal rate of return (IRR) or economic rate of return (ERR) is a rate of return used in capital budgeting to measure and compare the profitability of investments.

I wrote some R code to calculate the  internal rate of return (IRR) like this:

```
cal_irr <- function(amount,fee,duration) {
    cash<-c(amount,rep(-1*(amount*fee+amount/duration),duration))
    NPV<-function(r){sum(cash /((1 + r) ^ (seq(along.with = cash)-1)))}
    return(uniroot(NPV, c(0, 1))$root)
}
```

`cal_irr` can calculate Instalment Payments, but the annoying thing is that my result is different from the financial function `IRR` in MS Excel.

For example, you borrow 3600 from the bank, the administrative fee is `0.006*3600`, equal principal instalments in 24 months, so every month you have to pay `3600*0.006+3600/24=171.6`.

The cost you incur is `cal_irr(3600,0.006,240) = 0.01104071` per month, but in Excel I got `1.1054657%`. What is wrong with my R code?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are unirooting to find small numbers, which can cause issues with tolerance.  Try:

```
cal_irr <- function(amount,fee,duration) {
  cash<-c(amount,rep(-1*(amount*fee+amount/duration),duration))
  NPV<-function(r){sum(cash /((1 + r) ^ (seq(along.with = cash)-1)))}
  return(uniroot(NPV, c(0, 1), tol=.0000001)$root)}
cal_irr(3600,0.006,24)
# [1] 0.01105466
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a CF that looks like this:

```
> cal_cash <- function(amount,fee,duration) c(amount,rep(-1*(amount*fee+amount/duration),duration))
> cal_cash(3600,0.006,24)
 [1] 3600.0 -171.6 -171.6 -171.6 -171.6 -171.6 -171.6 -171.6 -171.6 -171.6 -171.6 -171.6 -171.6 -171.6 -171.6 -171.6 -171.6 -171.6 -171.6
[20] -171.6 -171.6 -171.6 -171.6 -171.6 -171.6
```

Then it's easy to use the `financial` package to compute the IRR:

```
> require(financial)
> cf(cal_cash(3600,0.006,24))$irr
[1] -185.755352    1.105466
```